# Can I checkout a project from one svn, and import it to another, but need to be to update from original svn?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

In our office we have checkout the contents of a framework which we do not have any commit access, but our office is working on several projects with it, to which we all have made changes to this framework but they do not interest framework creators, so we wondered if it is possible to import the framework with the changes we made to our own svn server, but:

- We need to update from the original svn repo (the one we done have access),
- We also need to be able to checkout to our svn.

To summarise, we need to be able to update the local code from the original svn, and be able to import it and checkout to our own svn. Keeping the log from the original svn is not necessary.

Before anyone suggests the lazy approach of exporting this to a folder and import it to our svn, due the size of the framework this is not duable since we would have to update the files manually.

I have looked everywhere and i cant seem to figure a way to do this. Does anyone knows if svn supports this?

Comment: What kind of framework? In which programming language ?

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading this correctly it sounds like you need to use 'Externals'. I've used these in the past to pull libraries out of one repo into my solution that was being committed to another repo.

[Take a look here](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-externals.html) and see if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: I will check this tomorrow, it doesnt look straightforward but by reading it, it sounds just what i need. I will confirm tomorrow.

Comment: Just been playing with this external but i really dont think this is what i need, this just updates contents from different repos to the same checkout dir, and checkout back to the same where they came from.
I need to checkout the project i have in my local computer to our repo, and to be able to update (the project) from the original location, and from our repo, but only to checkout to our repo (since we do not have permission to checkout the original repo).
Does it make more sense now? if externals can do this can you please give me a hand?

Comment: So, if I read this correctly, you need to be able to take updates from the readonly repository and to be able to make changes to the project/library locally. But, because you cannot commit the changes back to the original repo you want to include them with your project. If this is the case then I don't think that externals will get you there.
If you need updates and the ability to edit I think you will need to somehow get a copy of the project/library into the repo that you have commit access to and to be able to update/merge from the readonly repo somehow.

Comment: Thanks for ur reply @DilbertDave i really didn't thought that externals was the one after reading a few blog post and the documentation for tortoisesvn... Thanks for ur help though.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the supplementals you gave you should think about using a build system like Maven to handle such dependencies between modules and/or libraries instead of using SVN for that. If you really need to stuck with SVN you can use svn:externals to solve such problems.

Comment: I really dont get how can I use externals to do what i want, since it creates local copies of my (repo), instead of merging the content of both repos. and I cant use maven, also, the company only uses visual svn server:S @khmarbaise

Answer (score 0):

You have to search for "Vendor Branches" and combine Vendor Branches with externals, as suggested

I.e

- you have `<somelocation-in-repo>`, linked to HEAD (?) of 3-rd party repo with needed framework (RO)
- you have branch (or any other location) in repo, which is "framework with changes" (created initially as copy of somelocation-in-repo)
- from time to time, you have to merge `^/vendor/framework` with '^/branches/framework' (URLs are just examples)